# Get and echo multiple strings from a method

Tags: php, string, class, methods, properties

I'm fairly new with PHP and I am trying to understand working Classes, Methods and Properties. 
I've a problem that I want to get solved and that I don't get. I was unable to find a proper solution (that I also liked).

Before I ask my question here are my classes/code:

**Main class *User* (user.class.php)**

```
 class User {

    // Properties
    protected $_name;
    public $surname;

    // Methods
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->_name = $name;   
    }   

    public function getName() {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function setSurname($surname) {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    public function getSurname() {
        return $this->surname;
    }

}
```

**Child class *Premium_User* (premiumUser_child_user.class.php)**

```
class Premium_User extends User { 
    private $_premiumId;

    public function setData($name, $id) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->_premiumId = $id;
    }   

    public function getData() {
        return array(
        'name' => $this->name,
        'id' => $this->_premiumId
        );

    }   
}
```

**The code:**

```
 // Class User::

include('user.class.php');

// Child class -> class::User

include('premiumUser_child_user.class.php');

$user = new Premium_User(); 
$user->setData('P','1'); 
$user->setData('H','2'); 
$user->setData('P','3'); 

$getUserData = $user->getData();

while ($i <= $getUserData['id'] ) {
    echo "User: " . $getUserData['name'] . " ID: " . $getUserData['id'] . ".\n"; <br>
    $i++; 
}
```

**The output:**

```
User: P ID: 3. 
User: P ID: 3. 
User: P ID: 3.
```

What I would like to get it is:

```
User: P ID: 1.
User: H ID: 2. 
User: P ID: 3.
```

I tried to use *array_push* to add every entry to the array, but didn't work.

Comment: `class Premium_User extends User { <br>` rather strange place for a `<br>`?

Comment: You want to have 3 distinct users, right?

Comment: If you place each user into an array, it will.

Comment: I want to use unlimited users, but for now only three is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only create one single user instead of three independent ones. If you want to have three users, *create* three by using `new` three times.

You call `setData()` thrice on the same object.

```
public function setData($name, $id) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->_premiumId = $id;
}
```

By this definition, you *overwrite* the changes from the previous calls to the `setData` method. I have commented the lines that have *no effect* for you:

```
$user = new Premium_User();
// $user->setData('P','1');
// $user->setData('H','2');
$user->setData('P','3');
```

To have multiple users accessible through a single variable, you can put your users into an array:

```
$user1 = new Premium_User();
$user1->setData('P','1');
$user2 = new Premium_User();
$user2->setData('H','2');
$user3 = new Premium_User();
$user3->setData('P','3');
```

For use with PHP 5.4 and later:

```
$users = [$user1, $user2, $user3];
foreach($users as $user) {
    echo "User: " . $user->getData()['name'] . " ID: " . $user->getData()['id'] . ".\n";
}
```

Before PHP 5.4:

```
$users = array($user1, $user2, $user3);
foreach($users as $user) {
    $userData = $user->getData(); 
    echo "User: " . $userData['name'] . " ID: " . $userData['id'] . ".\n";
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it gives me an error at $users = [$user1, $user2, $user3]; - PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['. Doesn't work without braces either or as a string.

Comment: @Bilzard This syntax only works in PHP 5.4 and later. I updated my answer with an alternate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

the class only remembers the last time you set the data. either instantiate multiple users or set them one at a time and output them one at a time.

```
$user = new Premium_User();
$user->setData('P','1'); 

$user2 = new Premium_User();
$user2->setData('H','2'); 

$user3 = new Premium_User();
$user3->setData('P','3');
```

FYI the `<br>` tags are not needed until you use echo.

Or use:

```
$user = new Premium_User();
$user->setData('P','1');
//do something with this user data
$user->setData('H','2'); 
//do something with second user data
//etc.
```